# How do I test for results in a Braintree Customer search?

Tags: c#, braintree

```
        var searchReq = new CustomerSearchRequest().Email.Is(lk.email);
        var customers = gateway.Customer.Search(searchReq);
        var customer = customers.FirstItem;
```

When are no results, the FirstItem throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception. I can see a private field called Ids which has Count 0 as well as "MaximumCount" which is also 0. Is MaximumCount dependable?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The word 'dependable' is ambiguous, but the short answer is `yes`. The MaximumCount is intended to return the count of the entire result set for a search. [Result sets of over 100 are included in SDK integration tests for the library](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet/blob/master/Braintree.Tests/CustomerTest.cs#L913-L927).

Note that the Braintree API has [a limit of 10,000 results](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/searching/search-results/dotnet#search-limit) returned from a Customer search.

> Transaction searches return a maximum of 20,000 results; all other searches return a maximum of 10,000 results.

Comment: is there a  way way to search for a single customer using multiple parameters ? I.e.                                                                                                                     '''gateway.customer.search(function(search) {
    search.firstName().is(firstn);
 search.lastName().is(lastn);
 search.email().is(email);
 search.phone().is(fone);
  }, function(err, result){}); ''